# Linux file permissions not being preserved

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I am deploying some custom software as root (a necessity for this situation).

I set the owner/group to `user1:user1` and set all the files to `644` beforehand in shell, then copy and deploy with ant.

However, when files get copied over from the deployment directory, the ownership changes back to root and all the files install with `666` permissions.

This seems to occur whether the file is overwritten or newly created. I believe there is a way to set an option in `cp`, `mv` commands to preserve permissions, but that would be a lot of commands to change. How can I fix this?

Is there some setting I can change temporarily for root so the install always preserves the file permissions?

Comment: Are you using a script with lots of `cp` and `mv` commands? If yes it should be easy to change all of them with `sed` to use the options you need (see my answer below).

Comment: Yes I have a number of cp/mv commands, but they are occuring in my ant deploy.xml, so not shell script.

Answer (score 2):

`cp -p` will preserve your permissions. If you want the copy to be the closest possible you can simply use the "archive" option: `cp -a`. From `cp --help` you can double check it:

```
-a, --archive                same as -dR --preserve=all

-p                           same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
  --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]   preserve the specified attributes (default:
                             mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible
                             additional attributes: context, links, xattr,
                             all
```

Comment: This is not [available for ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), instead you have to use `exec` and `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you should be using [`install`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install) instead, which lets you explicitly specify all that.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Google didn't turn up any good explanations or examples.